# JSON_QUERY: Path expression based on variables?

Tags: json, oracle

is it possible to define the path expression in JSON_QUERY dynamically based on variables?

```
DECLARE
    varpath varchar(180):= 'testvar1.testattribute';
BEGIN
    SELECT (JSON_QUERY(json_field FORMAT JSON , '$.' || varpath RETURNING VARCHAR2(4000) ASIS  WITHOUT ARRAY WRAPPER NULL ON ERROR)) FROM example1; 
END;
```

The concatenation of `'$.' || varpath` leads to the error:

> PL/SQL: ORA-40454: path expression not a literal.

Is there any way to achieve this? In my use case, I need to fetch the path dynamically from other tables, that's why I built this short test script.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to solve it.

```
DECLARE
    varpath varchar2(180):= 'testvar1.testattribute';
    v_query_str varchar2(4000);
    v_result varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    v_query_str := 'SELECT JSON_QUERY(json_field FORMAT JSON , ''$.' || varpath || ''' RETURNING VARCHAR2(4000) ASIS  WITHOUT ARRAY WRAPPER NULL ON ERROR) FROM example1'; 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_str INTO v_result;
END;
```

Comment: Holy cow. Oracle really knows how to confuse and annoy programmers. But this does in fact work for me.